# How to pass multiple integer values from EditText in activity A to Text view in Activity B?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activities.

In activity A, I have 4 EditTexts that can only contain integer.
there is a button, that should calculate the average of those 4 numbers entered by user.

In activity B, there are 5 Text views (4 for numbers, 1 for result). 
when the button in activity A is pressed. 
It should pass the numbers from EditText in Activity A to Text View in Activity B, also should show the average of 4 numbers in Results Text view.

I watched so many tutorials, but they are only for one value and when I try to duplicate the code for more than one value the app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to send the values as "extras" of the Intent you use to start Activity B.

Here is a possible code for Activity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("1", num1);
i.putExtra("2", num2);
i.putExtra("3", num3);
i.putExtra("4", num4);
i.putExtra("average", result);
startActivity(i);
```

This code assumes you have the integers you want to send in separate variables num1 - num4, and calculated the average in another variable called "result".

To unpack this in Activity B, you would do something like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
textView1.setText(i.getIntExtra("1", 0); //0 is the default value in case the extra does not exist
textView2.setText(i.getIntExtra("2", 0);
textView3.setText(i.getIntExtra("3", 0);
textView4.setText(i.getIntExtra("4", 0);
resultView.setText(i.getIntExtra("average", 0));
```

You can also put your numbers in an array, and use one call to `putExtra` and one call to `getIntArrayExtra`.
This would be more elegant, but I wanted to demonstrate sending multiple separate numbers.

Answer (score 1):

1.Use the Intention Bundle to pass

activityA code sends data

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityB.class);
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("num1",10);
    bundle.putInt("num2",20);
    intent.putExtra("bun",bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

activityB code receives data

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
    Bundle bundle=intent.getBundleExtra("bun");
    int num1=bundle.getInt("num1",0);
    int num2=bundle.getInt("num2",0);
```

2.Use serialized object Seriazable

The implementation class

```
public class DataUtils implements Serializable {
 private int name;
 private int age;

    public String getName() {
         return name;
 }
 public void setName(int name) {
         this.name = name;
 }
 public int getAge() {
         return age;
 }
 public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
 }
```

}

activityA code sends data

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
 DataUtils dataUtils = new DataUtils();
 dataUtils.setAge(20);
 dataUtils.setName(10);
 intent.putExtra("du",dataUtils);
 startActivity(intent);
```

activityB code receives data

```
 Intent intent=getIntent();
 Serializable serializable=intent.getSerializableExtra("du");
 if (serializable instanceof DataUtils){
  DataUtils db=(DataUtils) serializable;
  int name=db.getName();
   int age=db.getAge();
 }
```

3.use sharedPreferences to pass data

4.Pass data using static variables of the class

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to use `Intent.putExtra()`, where you can store key-value pairs. Here's a short guide on how to do it: [How to use intent.putextra to pass data between activities](https://zocada.com/using-intents-extras-pass-data-activities-android-beginners-guide/)